# Calendar data sorting json tree

Tags: javascript, php, python, recursion, traversal

I need help with the following, 
Here is some json data

```
[
{
    "id"   : 1,
    "from" : 10,
    "to"   : 11
},
{
    "id"   : 2,
    "from" : 11,
    "to"   : 12
},
{
    "id"   : 3,
    "from" : 10.5,
    "to"   : 11.5
},
{
    "id"   : 4,
    "from" : 9,
    "to"   : 9.5
}   
]
```

I am trying to prepare the data like this I can display it on the screen, so each object will contain 2 additional properties, sum and col (column). Sum is the sum of columns (per say) that make up the group, and col is in which column the object sits. This is sample data. So I am looking for a recursive way to traverse the data to set those two additional properties. The data should now look like this:

```
[
{
    "id"   : 1,
    "from" : 10,
    "to"   : 11,
    "sum"  : 2,
    "col"  : 1
},
{
    "id"   : 2,
    "from" : 11,
    "to"   : 12,
    "sum"  : 2,
    "col"  : 1
},
{
    "id"   : 3,
    "from" : 10.5,
    "to"   : 11.5,
    "sum"  : 2,
    "col"  : 2
},
{
    "id"   : 4,
    "from" : 9,
    "to"   : 9.5,
    "sum"  : 1,
    "col"  : 1
}   
]
```

So because item id:3 from is between id:1 and id:2 from and to, notice the sum property of those three items is 2 and that the col of id:3 is 2. I guess this is a simple version of the data. Additional nesting could exist where for instance an additional object sum could equal 3 and col equal 3.

I am unsure what data structure this resembles? Some kind of tree. How can I  traverse these items (thinking recursive) and set those additional properties with least time complexity? Maybe I have sort first.

Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: But this is not JSON :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález this doesn't look like json ? Maybe missing some quotes?

Comment: so each object in this array is defining a range (.from -> .to), and you want to count the number of times each range overlaps other ranges?

Comment: i don't get it at all. Please explain in more detail what Sum and Position represent. Wich sum, wich position, and how do i compute them?

Comment: @RonBuenavida For instance. Data formats are normally not open to interpretation (except maybe CSV). If you are posting pseudocode you should explain it.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I completely agree. Updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign two properties for each array element. The `pos` is the schedule column in the list form. When there are two or more overlapping appointments, position 1 is for the first appointment, position 2 for the second, and so on.

```
          pos = 1                           pos = 2
---------------------------     -------------------------------
{ id: 1, from: 10, to: 11 }     { id: 3, from: 10.5, to: 11.5 }
{ id: 2, from: 11, to: 12 }
{ id: 4, from: 12, to: 13 }
```

The `sum` is, what I think I have understood, the count of simultaneous appointments.

For the first part, the solution uses a helper variable `schedule`. This variable simulates a table with the appointments. In every array, all appointments are non-overlapping. The array size corresponds to the wanted `pos`.

The second part calculates the `sum`, an indicator of how many appointments may even take place, simultaneously. Here, the greatest count is used.

The algorithm needs sorted data.

The first array in the result is the schedule.
The second is the original array, sorted and appended with the wanted properties `pos` and `sum`.

```js
var data = [
        { id: 1, from: 10, to: 11 },
        { id: 3, from: 10.5, to: 11.5 },
        { id: 2, from: 11, to: 12 },
        { id: 4, from: 12, to: 13 },
    ],
    schedule = [];

data.sort(function (a, b) { return a.from - b.from || a.to - b.to; });

data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    schedule.some(function (b, j) {
        if (b.length && b[b.length - 1].to <= a.from) {
            b.push(a);
            return true;
        }
    }) || schedule.push([a]);
});

schedule.forEach(function (a, i) {
    a.forEach(function (b) {
        b.pos = i + 1;
    });
})

data.forEach(function (a, i, aa) {
    var j, sum = 1;
    while (i + sum < data.length && data[i + sum].from < a.to && a.to <= data[i + sum].to) {
        sum++;
    }
    for (j = i; j < i + sum; j++) {
        if (!(aa[j].sum >= sum)) {
            aa[j].sum = sum;
        }
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(schedule, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```